# sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ".....": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update a column in Sqlite (android) but the log shows the following error. Could anyone please help me with solving it?

```
06-11 12:52:21.373: I/Database(355): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "@gmail": syntax error
06-11 12:52:21.373: E/Database(355): Error updating password=12345 using UPDATE user SET password=? WHERE COL_USERID = something@gmail.com
06-11 12:52:21.373: D/AndroidRuntime(355): Shutting down VM
06-11 12:52:21.373: W/dalvikvm(355): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-11 12:52:21.393: E/AndroidRuntime(355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 12:52:21.393: E/AndroidRuntime(355): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@gmail": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE user SET password=? WHERE COL_USERID = something @gmail.com
```

And here is my code:

```
public long updateUserPassword(String userid, String password) {
    ContentValues initialValues = 
            createUserPasswordContentValues(password);

    return database.update(LOGIN_TABLE, initialValues, "COL_USERID = "+userid, null);
}

private ContentValues createUserPasswordContentValues(String password) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_PASSWORD, password);
    return values;
}
```

Comment: I think you have add ticks arround the userid `"COL_USERID = '"+userid+"'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes missing. Use below code

```
return database.update(LOGIN_TABLE, initialValues, "COL_USERID = '"+userid+ "'", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace below line:

```
return database.update(LOGIN_TABLE, initialValues, "COL_USERID = '"+userid+"'", null);
```

Instead of:

```
return database.update(LOGIN_TABLE, initialValues, "COL_USERID = "+userid, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing single quotes in `"COL_USERID = "+userid` so use this  `"COL_USERID = '" + userid + "'"`
i.e.
Simply,Change this

```
   return database.update(LOGIN_TABLE, initialValues, "COL_USERID = "+userid, null);
```

to

```
return database.update(LOGIN_TABLE, initialValues, "COL_USERID = '" + userid + "'", null);
```